# GA4 Equivalent to UA Behavior Flow

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I am wondering if there is way to use GA4 Google Analytics Path Exploration to see a presentation identical to UA Google Analytics Behavior Flow with the first column of the flow representing the source (source being in the UTM tag, direct/google/whatever site refers the user to the target website). I am not able to use session source as a dimension for the GA4 path exploration for whatever reason (it's greyed out). Seems like the opposite of progress to lose functionality instead of gain... hope I'm wrong about not being able to do this.